# Finding a mismatch between two correlated columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large pandas dataframe which has two columns. One column is the unique code for an item and the second column contains the name of that item.

For example purposes lets say 'ID' has a unique code for an animal and 'Name' has the name of that animal.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['AA','BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE'], 
                   'Name': ['Ape', 'Bull', 'Chimp', 'Dog', 'Dog']})


    ID      Name
0   AA      Ape
1   BB      Bull
2   CC      Chimp
3   DD      Dog
4   EE      Dog
```

When I run the code below I will get false because there is one more unique item in the ID column than in the Name column

```
len(df['Code'].unique()) == len(df['Name'].unique())
```

My question is how can I find out which animal is being represented by two codes. Ideally I would like to end up with a dataframe that has:

```
    ID  Name
3   DD  Dog
4   EE  Dog
```

But as long as I can identify the animal being represented by more than one ID, I am happy with whatever solution gets the desired result.

Thanks

EDIT:

The dataframe contains duplicate rows, so a more realistic example that resembles the actual problem is a dataframe that looks like the one below:

```
    ID      Name
0   AA      Ape
1   BB      Bull
2   CC      Chimp
3   DD      Dog
4   EE      Dog
5   CC      Chimp
6   AA      Ape
7   DD      Dog
8   FF      Frog

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['AA','BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'CC', 'AA', 'DD', 'FF'], 
                   'Name': ['Ape', 'Bull', 'Chimp', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Chimp', 'Ape', 'Dog', 'Frog']})
```

Desired output is still to find which **ID** has been matched to two different animal names

```
    ID  Name
3   DD  Dog
4   EE  Dog
```

Comment: A solution depends on whether you may have duplicate rows in the dataframe.

Comment: Yes, you are spot on. My example was not clear enough. There are duplicates in the dataframe

Comment: `df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x: x['ID'].nunique() > 1).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','Name']).sort_values('Name')`. I'm not sure if this covers all possible cases.

Comment: Question was modified to include duplicated rows in the dataframe. @Michael's solution worked perfectly. The other solutions work for a dataframe that does not have duplicated rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a dataframe like the second example (containing duplicate rows) with a slightly augmented example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['AA','BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'CC', 'AA', 'DD', 'FF', 'AA'], 
                   'Name': ['Ape', 'Bull', 'Chimp', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Chimp', 'Ape', 'Dog', 'Frog','Bull']})
#    ID   Name
# 0  AA    Ape
# 1  BB   Bull
# 2  CC  Chimp
# 3  DD    Dog
# 4  EE    Dog
# 5  CC  Chimp
# 6  AA    Ape
# 7  DD    Dog
# 8  FF   Frog
# 9  AA   Bull
```

we can use the following. The result is sorted to make it easier to identify *ID* by *Name*.

```
df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x: x['ID'].nunique() > 1).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','Name']).sort_values('Name')
```

Output

```
   ID  Name
1  BB  Bull
9  AA  Bull
3  DD   Dog
4  EE   Dog
```

For dataframes with unique rows @ShubhamSharma's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72508767/14277722) is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby.filter` to filter which groups of names have `ID` count greater than or equal to 2.

```
>>> df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda s: s['ID'].count() >= 2)
```

---

```
    ID  Name
3   DD  Dog
4   EE  Dog
```

Answer (score 1):

If the column `ID` always contains unique values, then you can simply use:

```
df[df.duplicated('Name', keep=False)]
```

---

```
   ID Name
3  DD  Dog
4  EE  Dog
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do group by value counts

```
df.Name.value_counts()
```

```
Dog      2
Ape      1
Bull     1
Chimp    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want all rows where a `Name` has more than one `ID` you can use:

`df.groupby(['Name']).filter(lambda count: len(count) > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
aaa = df['Name'].value_counts()
m = aaa >= 2
index = aaa[m].index[0]
print(df[df['Name'] == index])
```

Output

```
   ID Name
3  DD  Dog
4  EE  Dog
```